# Find the ages of the three

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Mabvuto is half as old again as Matthew, Matthew is half as old again as Ngilazi. Given that the sum of their ages is 114, find their ages. My work just messes up, I need someone to help me!

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: Let $x$ be Mabvuto's age. Then Matthew's age is ?? and Ngilazi's is ??

Answer (score 4):

The key word is "again."  In English parlance, to say that Mabvuto is "half *again* as old" as Matthew means that Mabvuto is Matthew's age *plus* half Matthew's age.  That is, if we let $Mb$ denote Mabvuto's age and $Ma$ Matthew's, then $Mb = Ma + {1\over2}Ma= {3\over2}Ma$.  Likewise, the statement that Matthew is half again as old as Ngilazi implies $Ma = {3\over2}Ng$, where $Ng$ denotes Ngilazi's age.  Thus

$$114=Mb+Ma+Ng = {3\over2}Ma+{3\over2}Ng+Ng = {3\over2}\cdot{3\over2}Ng+{3\over2}Ng+Ng = {19\over4}Ng,$$

from which ones gets $Ng=24$, $Ma=36$, and $Mb=54$.

Comment: English 'as old again as' had confused me

Comment: @user83845, well now you know, and, one hopes, are half again as wise!  Does everything now make sense?

Answer (score -1):

Denote the respective ages as $x,y,z$. Then you are given 
$$ x=\frac12y$$
$$ y=\frac12z$$
$$x+y+z=114$$
You should be able to solve this.